# What creature did Q arrive as in "Hide and Q"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

In Q's second appearance, [Hide and Q](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hide_and_Q_%28episode%29), Q first arrives on the Enterprise as a glowing orb of light with three snakelike heads and several bright starbursts surrounding him.  He then changes into his usual form, wearing a Starfleet Admiral uniform.  He and Picard share this exchange:

> Picard: You're no Starfleet Admiral, Q!
>
> Q: I'm not a (Blank) either, but you took me for one all the same when I came onboard.

Not the exact wording, but approximately what he said.

What is the name of that creature that he arrived as and made that remark about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He appeared as an Aldebaran serpent, according to [the transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/111.htm), and [the original script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/111.txt).

> **PICARD:** *You're no Starfleet Admiral, Q.*
>   **Q:** *Neither am I an* **Aldebaran serpent,** *Captain, but you accepted me as such.*

[image]

Comment: Tourist Tip: Don't go to Aldebaran.  Their snakes are deadly and luminescent.

Comment: Great whiskey, though. http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Aldebaran_whiskey

Comment: And they say you can’t do movie-quality special effects on a TV budget.